# Is it possible to transfer Persona 4 Golden Vita save to PC?

Tags: persona-4-golden

With the addition of PC being a new way to play Persona 4 Golden, I don't want to spend another thousand hours playing, starting from scratch.

Is there a way I can bring over my completed save from my Vita to PC so I can start a NG+ right from the start?